# Fix width of drop down menu in select option

Tags: select, drop-down-menu

When I open my dropdown list, the width of list is greater than drop down box.
List width should same as drop down box.

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
select, option { width: __; }
```

Keep in mind this may not work on Google Chrome. If you want a cross-browser solution you will probably have to use PHP to clip the String with SubStr. You can probably also use jQuery to set the length of the option text.

```js
jQuery('#dropdown option').each(function() {
var optionText = this.text;
console.log(optionText);
var newOption = optionText.substring(0,19);
console.log(newOption);
jQuery(this).text(newOption + '..');
});
```

```css
select, option {
    width:150px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select id="dropdown" style="width:150px;">
                <option value="test">123123123123123123123123123123</option>
                <option value="test2">123123123123123123123123123123</option>
                <option value="test3">123123123123123123123123123123</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <input type="text">
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[**JsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/78h5hk3r/5/)

You will have to set the substring values of

```
var newOption = optionText.substring(0,19);
```

By yourself though.

Answer (score 2):

Try to set width of options same as select box

```
    #SelectBoxid {
  width:150px; 
}
 #SelectBoxid option{
   width:150px; 
}
```

Comment: I apply, but not fixed