# Option in select will be same width with the select css

Tags: html, css

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29508534/fix-width-of-drop-down-menu-in-select-option) question shares my problem, I tried the answer but it didn't work

```
#SelectBoxid {
  width:150px; 
}
 #SelectBoxid option{
   width:150px; 
}
```

Any way to make the option same width as select and if there is more text it can be just `...`

`UPDATE`

Pure css as much as possible no jquery..

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/bcrLh7k9/)

Comment: Please show your HTML and tell us which browser you're using.

Comment: I am using chrome safari IE opera and firefox but i use chrome more i will update question

Comment: are the options static or dynamic? if its dynamic, then you could simply use your server-side language to cut those strings..

Comment: no it is as written there i set the defined option. The option differ from words phrases to sentences

Comment: Possible duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7289769/ellipsis-for-overflow-text-in-dropdown-boxes

Answer (score 0):

After doing some research, I don't think it's possible to control `option`'s width without javascript. Its width depends on browser implementation.

There isn't a way to control this width in HTML standards.
[http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/option.html#option](http://The%20HTML%20standards%20don't%20allow%20for%20a%20way%20to%20control%20this%20width)

And support for CSS on form controls is rather weak.

This style is useless. It doesn't control option at all. If options are all short, then options' width are the same as `select` even you set width to `100px`. If any `option` is wider than `select`, then options' width are the same as the widest `option`. (at least in Chrome)

```
#category option {
  width:173px; // not works at all
}
```